# Sending out Database Document Ids (Security)

Tags: database, couchdb, database-security

I have a web app that stores objects in a database and then sends emails based on changes to those objects.  For debugging and tracking, I am thinking of including the Document Id in the email metadata.  Is there a security risk here?  I could encrypt it (AES-256).

In general, I realize that security through obscurity isn't good practice, but I am wondering if I should still be careful with Document Ids.

For clarity, I am using CouchDB, but I think this can apply to databases in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, CouchDB uses UUIDs with a UTC time prefix. The worst you can leak there is the time the document was created, and you will be able to correlate about 1k worth of IDs *likely* having been produced on the same machine.

You can change this in the CouchDB configuration to use purely 128bit random UUIDs by setting the `algorithm` setting within the `uuids` section to `random`. For more information see the [CouchDB Docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/misc.html?highlight=utc_id_suffix#uuids-configuration). Nothing should be possible to be gained from them.

Edit: If you choose your own document IDs, of course, you leak whatever you put in there :)

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I am using my own DocIds which do contain some user information.  I will keep that in mind as I decide if I want to encrypt or not.

Answer (score 1):

Compare Convenience and Security:

Convenience:

- how useful is it for you having the document id in the mail?
- can you quickly get useful information / the document having the ID ?
- does encrypting/hashing it mean it's harder to get the actual database document? (answer here is yes unless you have a nice lookup form/something which takes the hash directly, avoid manual steps )

Security:

- having a document ID what could I possibly do that's bad?
- let's say you have a web application to look at documents..you have the same ID in a URL, it can't be considered 'secret'
- if I have the ID can I access the 'document' or some other information I shouldn't be able to access. Hint: you should always properly check rights, if that's done then you have no problem.
- as long as an ID isn't considered 'secret', meaning there aren't any security checks purely on ID, you should have no problems.
- do you care if someone finds out the time a document was created? ( from Jan Lehnardt's answer )

Comment: middle ground option: put a UUID in each doc and put that in the email header and then use a view to correlate results for debugging.